# merging two stages of mongodb aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a series of prices like below in a mongodb collection:

```
id date       value
A  1 Jan 18   1
A  2 Jan 18   0
A  3 Jan 18   0
B  14 Jan 18  4
B  15 Jan 18  5
B  16 Jan 18  0
C  2 Jan 18   4
C  3 Jan 18   4
C  5 Jan 18   3
```

Using the mongodb aggregation pipeline (mongo 3.4), I am trying to find out for each id, on what date it's value changes to 0 from non-zero, as well as the "id group" for those records.

I have a way to find the first and last date when a record has a certain value:

```
{
    "$addFields": {
      "date": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "id": "$id",
        "value": "$value"
      },
      "first": {
        "$first": "$date"
      },
      "last": {
        "$last": "$date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id.value": 0
    }
  }
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/moBRI2Q7aGu

This gives me (notice id C is missing, as it has no 0 value):

```
id value   first      last
A  0       2 Jan 18   3 Jan 18
B  0       16 Jan 18  16 Jan 18
```

If I look at the "first" dates, those are the dates where value first becomes 0 from non-zero.

However, I would like to see the entire "id group" of those values that become 0 from non-zero at some point in time. So my expected result is:

```
id value   first      last
A  1       1 Jan 18   1 Jan 18
A  0       2 Jan 18   3 Jan 18
B  4       14 Jan 18  14 Jan 18
B  5       15 Jan 18  15 Jan 18
B  0       16 Jan 18  16 Jan 18
```

To get this, I need to access the group stage before the match of above pipeline, so https://mongoplayground.net/p/YTP-NBJtO4R, and filter this somehow with the resultset from the first aggregation pipeline. I do this in pandas via a left join on the first resultset, but this seems inelegant.

So now I have two different pipelines, which seems a bit inconvenient. Ideally the last resultset would come from a single aggregation pipeline. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should get you the output that you are looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "date": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      date: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "id": "$id",
        "value": "$value"
      },
      "first": {
        "$first": "$date"
      },
      "last": {
        "$last": "$date"
      },
      "data": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      first: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$_id.id",
      last_value: {
        $last: "$_id.value"
      },
      first_date_for_last_value: {
        $last: "$first"
      },
      last_date_for_last_value: {
        $last: "$last"
      },
      all_values: {
        $push: {
          id: "$$ROOT._id.id",
          value: "$$ROOT._id.value",
          first: "$first",
          last: "$last"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "last_value": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Optionally you can add $project and $unwind stages if all you want is the data from 'all_values'.